# WordPress Rest API : filtering posts by custom field value

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have created my own custom API end point in WordPress. I use it to get some data from some Custom Post Types for Vue.js to work with. Each of these custom posts is an event with an Advanced Custom Field that holds a date (event_date) for that event. I want to be able to retrieve events based on their date specifically the year.

Is there anyway I could add a filter to my end point that allows me to only get the events in a specific year based on the events event_date? This would have to be dynamic as the user will be able to change the year on the front end.

something like

```
/wordpress/wp-json/custom-routes/v1/events?event_date=2020
```

functions.php

```
    //api endpoint event lists
    add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
        register_rest_route('custom-routes/v1', 'events', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_events_data',
        ) );
    });

    // event list api endpoint output 
    function get_events_data() {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $query->have_posts() ):
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                $postID = get_the_id();
                $blog_data[] = array(
                    "title" => get_the_title(),
                    'event_location' => get_field('event_location', $postID),
                    "event_date" => get_field('event_date', $postID),
                    "event_speaker" => get_field('event_speaker', $postID),      
                    "permalink" => get_the_permalink(),
                );
            endwhile; 
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $blog_data;
    }
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/wordpress/wp-json/custom-routes/v1/events',
    error = (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    success = (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

api output:

```
[
{
title: "Event Four",
event_date: "May 30, 2021",
},
{
title: "Event Three",
event_date: "July 16, 2020",
},
{
title: "Event Two",
event_date: "May 11, 2021",
},
{
title: "Event One",
event_date: "May 24, 2020",
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by meta like in this example.

```
function get_events_data($data)
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'meta_value' => $data['year']
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    .....
}
```

Then change your router registration like so:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom-routes/v1', 'events(?:/(?P<year>\d+))?', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_events_data',
        'args' => [
            'year'
        ],
    ));
});
```